# Display thousands of records in CSV data in Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, canvas, tkinter

I want to load the data from a CSV file which have around 20,000 records and want to display it in tkinter in a scrollable table format. I used canvas, labels, grids, and scrollbar to achieve this. However, it can load only around 100-300 records in Tkinter without hanging. What could be the possible reason for this? I find that parsing through CSV is not the culprit. Is it the canvas and scrollable area? Can Tkinter show huge data as tables?

```
class Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, csv_data, start=0):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="#EEEEEE", height=400)
        self._widgets = []
        self._canvas = Canvas(self, width=1300, height=500)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")  # changed
        self._vertical_bar = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._canvas.yview)
        self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        self._horizontal_bar = Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._canvas.xview)
        self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)
        self.frame = Frame(self._canvas)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        lineNum = start-1;
        for row in csv_data:
            print(lineNum)
            lineNum += 1;
            if lineNum < start:
                continue;
            if lineNum == start+200:
                break;
            current_row = []
            #index
            for column in range(len(row)+1):
                v = StringVar()
                label = Label(self.frame, textvariable=v)
                label.config(font=("Calibri", 10), background="white",highlightcolor='white', highlightbackground='white', borderwidth=0)
                label.grid(row=lineNum, column=column+1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                current_row.append(label)
                if column == 0:
                    v.set(lineNum)
                else:
                    v.set(row[column-1])

            self._widgets.append(current_row)

        for column in range(lineNum):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

    def resize(self, event=None):
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))
        #self._canvas.itemconfig(self.frame, height=500, width=1300)
        #self.__canvas.itemconfigure("self.frame", width=1300)

    def set(self, row, column, value):
        widget = self._widgets[row][column]
        widget.configure(text=value)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps see [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580793-tkinter-table-with-scrollbars/).

Comment: Another table widget which is pretty easy to use. Look at *Answer 1* in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358084/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-selected-cell-in-tkinter/48361639#48361639) and be sure to download the tktable widget (as per the comments under Answer 1).

Comment: The canvas is not unlimited in size.

Comment: I decided to used pandastable to load CSV data as a table in Tkinter. I dont know what was the issue with my code. But, pandastable looks cool and have lot of excel sheet like features. Thanks all for the comments, But if you can give me an insight on why my canvas failed, it would be helpful.