# How can i change the color background to row in treeview ( python tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

i building with tkinter a tree view that display me a lot of data and i want when in column 5 there is the word "free" the color background of the row will be yellow how can i do that?
ty for your help

```
def Read():
    Database()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `tbl_Employees")
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    txt_result.config(text="Successfully read the data from database", fg="green")
    txt_result.after(2000, clear_txt)
```

i tried to insert

```
if data[5] == 'free':
   ....??
```

but i dont know what the right command in the if block that going to do what i want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-selected-cell-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358084)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def Read():
    Database()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `tbl_Employees")
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5],))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    txt_result.config(text="Successfully read the data from database", fg="green")
    txt_result.after(2000, clear_txt)
```